# If URL not equal to specified URL then apply this jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, url, jquery-events

if the current uURL is not same as specified then apply jQuery. BUT THIS WONT WORK

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myurl = http://example.com/document.html;
var currenturl = window.location
if(myurl == currenturl) {
    $("<span>url's match</span>").replaceAll("body"); // check replaceWith() examples
}
</script>
```

Also current URL can be a standard link `http://example.com/` or as shown in example.

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: are you looking for the appropiate not equal synthax? it is != if you're not searching for that I didn't get your question.

Comment: -1 until you explain your question

Comment: So you're wanting to replace the `body` element with a `span` element if the current page's URL is not the one you want it to be?

Comment: yes precisely if the current url is not equal to specified domain replace the <body tag with <span tag.

Comment: You realize that doesn't make any sense? You want to set the `body` tag's `.html()` equal to your span, not replace the `body` tag altogether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to quote your URL:

```
var myurl = http://site.com/document.html;

// Should be
var myurl = "http://site.com/document.html";
```

For best practice, don't omit the `;` here:

```
var currenturl = window.location
//---------------------------^^^^
```

Comment: bzlm what do you mean.. and thankyou michael that worked perfectly

Comment: @user975763 - bzlm was being rude. Please upvote and mark as the answer (by clicking the outlined checkmark next to this answer).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes on the first line:

```
var myurl = "http://site.com/document.html";
```

And it should be != on the third line